# Kotlin extension field for SharedPreference value by string constant key

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, extension-function

Extension functions are great for the SharedPreference api in android. Jake Wharton has an interesting implementation at time code 32:30 of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A2LukgT2mKc&t=1461s) video tutorial where he implements SharedPreferences extension function like so:

```
preferences.edit{
    set(USER_ID /*some string key constant somewhere*/, 42)
    //...
}
```

while this is ok, its kind of verbose.

[This](https://medium.com/@krupalshah55/manipulating-shared-prefs-with-kotlin-just-two-lines-of-code-29af62440285) tutorial by Krupal Shah explains how you can reduce the getter/setter extension functions of SharedPreferences to:

```
preferences[USER_ID] = 42 
Log.i("User Id", preferences[USER_ID]) //User Id: 42
```

This is pretty good, but the brackets imply iterable semantics, IMO. While not the worst thing in the world, you just wish that you could implement a field extension of a SharedPreferences value by the key constant itself.

My question is, is there any way to implement this type of extension on SharedPreferences?

```
preferences.USER_ID = 42
Log.i("User Id", preferences.USER_ID) //User Id: 42
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's create general interface for providing instance of `SharedPreferences`:

```
interface SharedPreferencesProvider {

    val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
}
```

After we have to create delegate for property which will read/write value to preferences:

```
object PreferencesDelegates {

    fun string(
        defaultValue: String = "",
        key: String? = null
    ): ReadWriteProperty<SharedPreferencesProvider, String> = 
        StringPreferencesProperty(defaultValue, key)
}

private class StringPreferencesProperty(
    private val defaultValue: String,
    private val key: String?
) : ReadWriteProperty<SharedPreferencesProvider, String> {

    override fun getValue(
         thisRef: SharedPreferencesProvider, 
         property: KProperty<*>
    ): String {
        val key = key ?: property.name
        return thisRef.sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue)
    }

    override fun setValue(
        thisRef: SharedPreferencesProvider,
        property: KProperty<*>, 
        value: String
    ) {
        val key = key ?: property.name
        thisRef.sharedPreferences.save(key, value)
    }
}
```

`PreferencesDelegates` needed to hide implementation and add some readability to code. In the end it can be used like this:

```
class AccountRepository(
    override val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
) : SharedPreferencesProvider {

    var currentUserId by PreferencesDelegates.string()
    var currentUserName by string() //With import
    var currentUserNickname by string(key = "CUSTOM_KEY", defaultValue = "Unknown")

    fun saveUser(id: String, name: String) {
        this.currentUserId = id
        this.currentUserName = name
    }
}
```

Similar can be implemented `int`, `float` or even custom type:

```
open class CustomPreferencesProperty<T>(
    defaultValue: T,
    private val key: String?,
    private val getMapper: (String) -> T,
    private val setMapper: (T) -> String = { it.toString() }
) : ReadWriteProperty<SharedPreferencesProvider, T> {

    private val defaultValueRaw: String = setMapper(defaultValue)

    override fun getValue(
        thisRef: SharedPreferencesProvider, 
        property: KProperty<*>
    ): T {
        val key = property.name
        return getMapper(thisRef.sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValueRaw))
    }

    override fun setValue(
        thisRef: SharedPreferencesProvider, 
        property: KProperty<*>, 
        value: T
    ) {
        val key = property.name
        thisRef.sharedPreferences.save(key, setMapper(value))
    }
}
```

I wrote small library which covers such case. You can find rest of implemented preferences [here](https://github.com/dewarder/AndroidKommons/tree/master/akommons/src/main/java/com/dewarder/akommons/content/preferences)

**EDIT**. In case if you are using dagger:

```
class AccountRepository @Injcet constructor() : SharedPreferencesProvider {

    @Inject
    override lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    var currentUserId by PreferencesDelegates.string()
    ...

}
```

Comment: I love the OOP of implementing a SharedPrefsProvider interface. However, I was hoping to @Inject a singleton SharedPreferences instance (default) and call the extension field on that injected instance provided by dagger

Comment: @flopshot you can do `override lateinit var sharedPreferences` and initalize it in the way you want

Comment: might I ask if you could elaborate in your answer?

Comment: @flopshot I've added example

Comment: Thanks, just looking it over. Question, when the key is null (not specified in the delegate) it defaults in getValue/setValue to property.name. What does that mean?

Comment: It means in case if you don't specify key for shared preferences explicitly it takes name of property instead. For example, if you write `var currentUserId by string()` it takes `currentUserId` as key for preference

Comment: Nice! Thanks again for the info. I'd like to tweak that null key default behavior a bit, but all in all great stuff.

Comment: This saved my day. This is what I wanted to do. Defining multiple keys for different preferences were killing me. Thanks a lot for this approach :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a simple extension property with a getter and a setter

```
var SharedPreferences.userId
    get() = getInt(USER_ID, 0)
    set(value: Int) { edit().putInt(USER_ID, value).apply() }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I should have mentioned in the question that Jake and Krupal's implementation doesn't require the boiler plate of writing an extension for EVERY shared preference. I was hoping to keep that feature.